# Set a text field within a ajax request receipt

Tags: html, ajax, textfield

I want to display some text on a text area upon a response from an ajax request.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b></b> <%=session.getAttribute( "username" )%> </p>
    </div>

    <!-- This div will contain the chatlog. --> 
    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <form name="message" action="" method="post">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to set 'chatbox' text within an ajax request response. 
This is the css document for chatbox

```
#chatbox {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:270px;
    width:430px;
    border:1px solid #ACD8F0;
    overflow:auto; }
```

This is the ajax call

```
function loadLog(){     
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "HandleMessage",
        //contentType: "application/json", 
        /*data: {
            card: JSON.stringify(card)
        },*/
        success: function(response) {                
            if(response != null)
            {
                $("#chatbox").attr("value", "aa"); // I want to concat current value and response here
            }               
                //document.getElementById('chatbox').value = 'fff';
                //alert(response);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('errorr');
            }
    });
```

Tried many things, but didn't work.

Tried,

```
$("#chatbox").attr("value", response);
$("#chatbox).val(response);
$(".chatbox").html(response);
```

Comment: use `$("#chatbox").html('whatever')` But why is it a `textarea` and not a `div` or any other normal element? textareas are for sending data to the server, not displaying things to the user.

Comment: Works! Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a simpler way to concat the response other than taking the current value and adding the response to it?

Comment: I didn't really get it..where do you concat it in the code?

Comment: Place where I need $("#chatbox").html(stringvalue), stringvalue should be the current value of text field + response

Comment: simplest way - `$("#chatbox").html( $("#chatbox").html() + 'whatever')` or like this: `$("#chatbox")[0].innerHTML += 'whatever'` which is shorter.

Comment: It returns function (E){return E===g?(this[0]?this[0].innerHTML.replace(/ jQuery\d+="(?:\d+|null)"/g,""):null):this.empty().append(E)}  +  the response.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the preferred way of writing AJAX using jQuery (with deferreds)

```
$.ajax({
    type        : "GET",
    url         : "HandleMessage",
    contentType : "application/json", 
    data        : {
        card: JSON.stringify(card)
    }
})
.done(function(RES){
    if( RES )
        $("#chatbox")[0].innerHTML += RES;

})
.fail(function(){
    alert('error');
});
```

Comment: `$("#chatbox")[0].innerHTML = $("#chatbox")[0].innerHTML + '\n' + response;`  doesn't add a new line?

Comment: Great. Appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) when updating an input value field

```
$('#chatbox').val('aa')
```

In the comment you ask about concatenating the existing field value with the respones:

```
$('#chatbox').val($('#chatbox').val() + response)
```

Comment: How can I concat current text field value with response?

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution :

```
$("#chatbox").html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent) you can write in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('chatbox').textContent+= response;
```

An example, based on github api, is reported in the following snippet (I did not use any format on the output. This is only an example.)

If you neet to get JSON data, using jQuery you may use directly [getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```js
function loadLog(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = document.getElementById('usermsg').value;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/repos",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {'name': name},
    success: function (response) {
      if (response != null) {
        document.getElementById('chatbox').textContent += JSON.stringify(response,response, 4, 4);
      }
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert('errorr');
    }
  });
}

window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('submitmsg').addEventListener('click', loadLog, false);
}
```

```css
#chatbox {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 270px;
  width: 430px;
  border: 1px solid #ACD8F0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b></b> &lt;%=session.getAttribute( "username" )%&gt; </p>
    </div>

    <!-- This div will contain the chatlog. -->
    <div id="chatbox"></div>

    <form name="message" action="" method="post">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63"/>
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help